# Can Django do nested queries and exclusions

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I need some help putting together this query in Django.  I've simplified the example here to just cut right to the point.

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    data = models.BooleanField()
```

The query I'd like to create in English would sound like:

*Give me every record that was created yesterday for which data is False where in that same range data never appears as True for the given user*

Here's an example input/output in case that wasn't clear.

**Table Values**

```
ID   Created    User    Data

1    1/1/2010   admin   False
2    1/1/2010   joe     True
3    1/1/2010   admin   False
4    1/1/2010   joe     False
5    1/2/2010   joe     False
```

**Output Queryset**

```
1    1/1/2010   admin   False
3    1/1/2010   admin   False
```

What I'm looking to do is to exclude record #4. The reason for this is because in the given range "yesterday", data appears as True once for the user in record #2, therefore that would exclude record #4.

In a sense, it almost seems like there are 2 queries taking place.  One to determine the records in the given range, and one to exclude records which intersect with the "True" records.

How can I do this query with the Django ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a nested query. You can generate a list of bad users' PKs and then exclude records containing those PKs in the next query.

```
bad = list(set(MyModel.obejcts.filter(data=True).values_list('user', flat=True)))
# list(set(list_object)) will remove duplicates
# not needed but might save the DB some work

rs = MyModel.objects.filter(datequery).exclude(user__pk__in=bad)
# might not need the pk in user__pk__in - try it
```

You could condense that down into one line but I think that's as neat as you'll get. 2 queries isn't so bad.

Edit: You might wan to read the docs on this:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

It makes it sound like it auto-nests the query (so only one query fires in the database) if it's like this:

```
bad = MyModel.objects.filter(data=True).values('pk')
rs  = MyModel.objects.filter(datequery).exclude(user__pk__in=bad)
```

***But*** MySQL doesn't optimise this well so my code above (2 full queries) can actually end up running a lot faster.

Try both and race them!

Comment: Very cool.  I adapted the pattern to my actual implementation and it works great.  I also learned some neat tricks along the way.  I think the `__in` was the main secret ingredient I was after.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you could use:
from django.db.models import F
`MyModel.objects.filter(datequery).filter(data=False).filter(data = F('data'))`

`F` object available from version `1.0`

Please, test it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to lazy evaluation, you can break your query up into a few different variables to make it easier to read.  Here is some `./manage.py shell` play time in the style that Oli already presented.

```
> from django.db import connection
> connection.queries = []
> target_day_qs = MyModel.objects.filter(created='2010-1-1')
> bad_users = target_day_qs.filter(data=True).values('user')
> result = target_day_qs.exclude(user__in=bad_users)
> [r.id for r in result]
[1, 3]
> len(connection.queries)
1
```

You could also say `result.select_related()` if you wanted to pull in the user objects in the same query.